# Why isn't broom::glance working with the gam package?

Tags: r, dataframe, modeling

If I try to run an example from the [`broom` package PDF](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/broom/broom.pdf), I'm getting an error. This is because `mgcv` is being loaded by the `car` package. However, even when I after I unload `car` and `mgcv`, `broom::glance` still fails.

How can I get the `broom` package work with `gam::gam` and have other packages loaded?

```
library(reshape2); library(plyr); library(stringr); library(lubridate); 
library(knitr); library(sp); library(rgeos); library(lme4); library(formatR);
library(rgdal); library(ggmap); library(maptools); library(Hmisc); library(raster); 
library(car); library(extrafont); library(openNLP); library(effects); library(psych); 
library(MuMIn); library(GPArotation); library(tuneR); library(gdata); library(xlsx); 
library(combinat); library(stargazer); library(grid); library(scales); library(dplyr); 
library(english); library(repmis); library(pscl); library(testthat); library(broom); 
library(ggplot2); library(geosphere); library(moult); library(GGally); library(pavo); 
library(stringi); library(mgcv); library(gam)

detach(package:car, unload = TRUE)
detach(package:mgcv, unload = TRUE)

if (require("gam", quietly = TRUE)) {
        data(kyphosis)
        g <- gam::gam(Kyphosis ~ s(Age,4) + Number, family = binomial, data = kyphosis)
        tidy(g)
        augment(g)
        glance(g)
}

    Warning: namespace ‘mgcv’ is not available and has been replaced
by .GlobalEnv when processing object ‘kyphosis’
Warning: namespace ‘mgcv’ is not available and has been replaced
by .GlobalEnv when processing object ‘kyphosis’
Warning: namespace ‘mgcv’ is not available and has been replaced
by .GlobalEnv when processing object ‘kyphosis’
Warning: namespace ‘mgcv’ is not available and has been replaced
by .GlobalEnv when processing object ‘kyphosis’
Warning: namespace ‘mgcv’ is not available and has been replaced
by .GlobalEnv when processing object ‘kyphosis’
Warning: namespace ‘mgcv’ is not available and has been replaced
by .GlobalEnv when processing object ‘kyphosis’
Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, "logLik", value = numeric(0)) : 
  replacement has 0 rows, data has 1
```

Comment: You have the packages `mgcv` and `gam` loaded at the same time. They both export a function called `gam` which will cause a namespace clash. Try running your code again without loading `mgcv`.

Comment: I'm not loading `mgcv`, can you see what package is loading it? Moreover, I don't see why using `gam::gam` doesn't solve having `mgcv` loaded

Comment: Look in the list of packages under "loaded via a namespace (and not attached)". R's handling of namespaces and packages is a bit glitchy; basically, don't count on stuff working when different packages try to define the same object.

Comment: I'm aware that `mgcv` is being loaded, but how can I prevent it being loaded?

Comment: @luciano With regard to why using `gam::gam` doesn't fix `mgcv` being loaded: the problem is not (just) that `gam` is being masked, but that S3 methods such as `logLik.gam` are masked; those are called within `glance`. I'm not sure where mgcv is being loaded, but it looks like you've already loaded a *lot* of packages. (Presumably you wouldn't get this error in a fresh session). Are you able to run it in a fresh session? If not, you could try running `detach("package:mgcv", unload = TRUE)`

Comment: @DavidRobinson The `kyphosis` example works without any other packages being loaded, but when I try to load my list of packages it fails. Attempts at using `detach("package:mgcv", unload = TRUE)` have also failed, question updated.

Comment: You could try loading `gam` last instead of first, and then maybe `gam` will mask `mgcv` functions rather than the other way around.

Comment: @Gregor @DavidRobinson Tried that and have also now figured our that `car` is loading `mgcv`. But even after removing `car` and `mgcv`, `glance` still fails. If I don't load both of `car` and `mgcv`, then `glance` works...but I need `car` elsewhere in code

Comment: Yes, start small and work up instead of starting with a big mess of code. Use a fresh R session, load only broom and gam, and see if it works. If so, add more packages one at a time and see where it fails. Then assess if you actually need that package.